# How to shorten this VBA code?

Tags: vba

How can I shorten this code? I want to make this code with `If` shorter in loop. I tried do something like this `Me.Controls("x" & t) = 0` , but it's returning a syntax error. I don't know what I can do. Please help.

```
x = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 16))
Dim x1 As Byte = 0
...
Dim x30 As Byte = 0

For t = 0 To 15
If x = t And x1 = 0 Then
...
End If
If x = t And x2 = 0 Then
...
End If
...
If x = t And x30 = 0 Then
...
End If
```

Comment: do you know how to use arrays?

Comment: If you included your *actual real working code*, this would be a nice question to ask on [codereview.se] =)

Comment: I am waiting for the famous [`For-Case`](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm) paradigm to show up as an answer now.

Comment: It is never a good idea to have `x1,x2,x3...x30`, Use arrays instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array are the best solution. First decide whether its one or two dimensional and then you can use it. I beleive yours is a two dimensional array.

You can set X1 to X30 in array and fetch the values. A mock code for both one and two dimensional array is here

**1-D Array:**

> ```
> Dim Films(1 To 5) As String
>
>  Films(1) = "Lord of the Rings"
>  Films(2) = "Speed"
>  Films(3) = "Star Wars"
>  Films(4) = "The Godfather"
>  Films(5) = "Pulp Fiction"
>
>  MsgBox Films(4)
> ```

**2-D Array**

> ```
> Dim Films(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As String
> Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
>
> For i = 1 To 5
>      For j = 1 To 2
>          Films(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
>      Next j
> Next i
>
>  MsgBox Films(4, 2)
> ```

Please mark it as answer if this help(can help someone too).

Regards,
Mani

Comment: Or:  
`Dim Films as variant`  
`Films = array("Lord of the Rings","Speed","Star Wars","The Godfather","Pulp Fiction")`  
This way the film variant can resize simply by adding or removing values, no need to specify a size.